# Opening firebase image in a new activity

Tags: android, listview, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

This is `ImageListActivity` and I want open the image in another activity.
But I don't know how to code this.
I need some help.

```
public class ImageListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private List<ImageUpload> imgList;
    private ListView lv;
    private ImageListAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_list);
        imgList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewImage);
        //Show progress dialog during list image loading
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Por favor aguarde...");
        progressDialog.show();

        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(MainActivity.FB_DATABASE_PATH);
        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                //Fetch imagem data from firebase database
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //ImageUpload  class require default constructor
                    ImageUpload img = snapshot.getValue(ImageUpload.class);
                    imgList.add(img);
                }
                //Init adapter
                adapter = new ImageListAdapter(ImageListActivity.this, R.layout.image_item, imgList);
                //Set adapter for listview
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Opening an image in another activity? Can't you just send the image to the activity by adding it to an intent (`using putExtra()`) and then open when activity starts up? I bet that'd be easier.

Comment: Yes, but the image comes from the firebase and stays on the listview

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this you can save your image into a `putExtra` , and then retrieve this image from your other activity, so you can handle it and do whatever you want with it there:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sticky_notes);// your bitmap
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bs);
intent.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
```

Here you create a bitmap with a random drawable (you can choose how you get your image) and after that I put that image into a putExtra with the key "byteArray"

In your other activity and do this:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")
{
    ImageView imv= new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
    imv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

`imv` is your imageView, in which you will put your image.

So at the line `ImageUpload img = snapshot.getValue(ImageUpload.class);`
You get your image, and then put that image into the putExtra and retrieve it into your other activity.